# Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 Process taking up 30% CPU for a long time after commit

Tags: git, process, cpu, utilization

VS2013 update 3 didn't hang before I had to exclude tons of files on a move. Is it doing this to anyone else? If so, how do we fix this? Thank you!

[image: VS 2013 Taking 30%+ consistently after commit]

[image: What my commit looks like, perhaps it's the large # of excluded changes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why it was halting, it was a directory with tons of files in there, and VS or Git keeps on comparing all those files together every time I commit. So I removed that folder as a workaround to the problem. The .gitignore file doesn't seem to be working.